# Height of UIViews proportional to height of Screen (Auto Layout)

Tags: ios, autolayout

I would like to make the **height** of the `UITextFields` and one `UIButton` I have into my view **proportional** when the height of the screen changes. The default height of the textfields and uibutton is 55, but I realised that in iPhone 4, this height doesn't fit propertly the screen.

How would you approach this thing with Auto Layout?

**iPhone 4.7 inch**

[image]

**iPhone 4.5 inch**

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: enclose all those elemtns in a uiview and constraint that view leading,trailing,top and bottom to the screen.

Comment: do not give height/width constraint for the elelemts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize Uiview with Auto Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455945/resize-uiview-with-auto-layout)

Comment: give equal widths to all textField ,top spacing for the logo and bottom space to the button . keep the constraints in order accordingly

Comment: I will try the solution proposed by Mr T, and I let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely not sure changing the height of textfields is the right approach to addressing your layout issues, but if you actually want to do so, it's as simple as creating an "Equal Height" constraint between your textfield and the view, and changing the multiplier so you get the value you want.

Comment: I thought in changing the height for iPhone 4 of all of them through a Constraint by code, I didn't know about the multiplier. I'll try it thanks!

Comment: Note that this will most probably give very weird results if you keep the same layout on an iPad! You may want to use a combination of constant and multiplier to avoid having something fully proportional.